# How to check if the DELETE API has been called

Tags: java, service, message-queue

I have a task to implement a distributed Queuing System something like the Amazon SQS.

If there is GET Request, I have to deliver the message to the user from the main queue and put the message in the invisible queue. And immediately a DELETE Request should come and I should delete the message from the invisible queue.

In case there is no DELETE Request, I am supposed to increase the redelivery count and send the message back to the main queue. This will happen till the redelivery count becomes 5 after which I will delete the message permanently.

Now my doubt is, **how do I know that there has been no DELETE request which means that I should send the message back to the main queue?**

My program works for the case where the DELETE Request follows the GET Request. I am using java for this implementation.

Comment: you should establish a window of time where delete is requested. say 30 seconds. after that time, the system will act as if no delete was recevied

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'm confused as to how I can implement that. Are you saying that I wait for about a minute then check if the message I last tried to deliver is there in the invisible queue and if it is, I should put it back? It seems like the wrong solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, at the design level, the get and delete should be done in one action.  Notice that [in the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), the `pull()` operation of `Queue` will do get and delete. if you insist on separate actions, at the very least you should support an optional get-and-delete request type.

now, there is a problem when you want to detect an action that **did not** happen because it can forever "maybe happen in the future".  So you need to set a window of time after which you decide that the expected action did not happen.

what is usually done is that you attach a "received" timestamp to the request (and also re-deliver count) before putting it in the invisible queue (a better name would be "pending delete requests" queue) you can wrap the request in a custom java class that adds the properties.

actually, I don't think a queue is a good choice for a collection.  when a delete request does come, you need random access to the request. so perhaps a hash map is a better choice.

you will need to implement a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that invokes tasks every x seconds.  the tasks will scan the `pendingDeleteRequests` map for requests that did not recevie delete in the allowed window of time and remove from the map.

last note: some messaging systems have ["dead letter"](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DeadLetterChannel.html) feature, which is a destination where notices of failed deliveries are sent.  this will help in debugging of problems.

Comment: I'm implementing the queue as a LinkedHashMap(actually, there is one HasMap of three LinkedHashMaps that act as multiple queues). And yes, I thought of implementing the dead letter feature as well but that will be after this works.

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to do it!